# Am I right understanding a least point theorem in general vector space?

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

The theorme is as follows

> Let $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space, and let $W$ be a finite-dimensional subspace of $V$. then there is at least one closest point $w^*\in W$ to $v$.
>   that is there is $w^*\in W$ such that $\|v-w^*\|=\inf\{\|v-w\|:w \in W\}$

Proof is introduced as follows

Notice that the zero vector is in $W$, and so 
$$
\inf\{\|v-w\|:w \in W\} \le \|v-0\|=\|v\|
$$
Let $M=\|v\|$. If $w$ satisfies $\|v-w\| \le \|v\|$, then
$$
\|w\| \le \|w-v\|+\|v\| \le M+M=2M
$$
Thus if we define $K :=\{w \in W : \|w\| \le 2M \}$,then

(now, my curious part is here)
$$
**\inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in K \} = \inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in W\}**
$$

the book prove subsequently without any explanation. So I was trying to fill the skipped part. Please check my thought.

Let
$$\rho_{1}(w)=\inf\{\|v-w\| : w\in W\} $$
$$ \rho_{2}(w)=\inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in K\}$$
then by above 
$$0 \le \rho_{1}(w), \rho_{2}(w)\le M$$
since we can select $M \ge 0$ by choosing arbitrary $v \in V$, then for all $M \ge 0$
$$
0\le |\rho_{1}(w)-\rho_{2}(w)| \le M 
$$ 
Thus 
$$\rho_1(w)=\rho_2(w)$$ the proof is finished.

I want to check my solution is right and if there is another solution above, please give me a information.

Comment: A proof MUST use the finite dimensionality of W. It is not true in some cases when W is infinite-dimensional/

Answer (score 1):

Since $K \subseteq W$, we have:

$$\inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in K \} \geq \inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in W\}$$

On the other hand, if $w \in W$ is such that $\|v-w\|\leq \|v\|$, then by the above argument we have $w \in K$. Thus, $\{w \in W : \|v-w\|\leq \|v\|\} \subseteq K$ so:

\begin{align}\inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in W\} &= \inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in W\text{ such that } \|v-w\|\leq \|v\|\}\\ &\geq \inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in K \}\end{align}

Thus: 
$$\inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in K \} =\inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in W\}$$

Regarding your proof, you probably mean to write
$$\rho_{1}(v)=\inf\{\|v-w\| : w\in W\}$$
$$\rho_{2}(v)=\inf\{\|v-w\| : w\in K\}$$

since $w$ is only a dummy variable inside the set; the real dependence is on $v$.

You actually showed that $\lim_{v\to 0}|\rho_1(v) 
- \rho_2(v)| = 0$, which is in fact easy to see since as $v\to 0$ you will eventually have $\|v\|\leq 2M$.

However, this is not what you had to prove: you should prove that for a **fixed** $v \in V$ we have $\rho_1(v) = \rho_2(v)$.

Comment: I realized the point where I have a fault, and understand most of your solution but one thing is not understand. that is part as follows "$\inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in W\} = \inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in W s.t \|v-w\| \le \|v\|\}$

Comment: @fivestar Since we know that $\inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in W\} \leq \|v\|$ we can restrict ourselves to just those $w$ for which $\|v-w\| \leq \|v\|$:

\begin{align}\inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in W\} &= \inf \Big(\{\|v-w\| : w \in W\}\cap\big[0, \|v\|\big]\Big)\\ &= \inf\{\underbrace{\|v-w\|}_{\leq \|v\|} : w \in W \text{ such that } \|v-w\| \leq \|v\|\}\end{align}

Comment: oh thank you! I understand. I envy your mathematical ability. 
some day I hope to be a person who can help like you .

Comment: Where did you use the finite-dimensionality of K? It's not true for all infinite-dimensional K.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You mean finite-dimensionality of $W$? I guess it is used at some point later in the proof. I just proved that $\inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in K \} = \inf\{\|v-w\| : w \in W\}$, which seems to be true for any subspace $W$. My guess is that the further proof is going to involve the compactness of $K$ to show that the function $x \mapsto d(x, w^*)$ attains a minimum on $K$.

Comment: I was rushed and only skimmed your A.  My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution doesn't work, because the vector $v$ is given here, so you can can't choose it at will, so as to satisfy such and such conditions.

Here is short proof of the assertion:

As you observed, $\;\inf_\limits{w\in W}\|v-w\|\le M $. Now
$$\inf_\limits{w\in W}\|v-w\|=\inf_\limits{w\in K}\|v-w\|$$
simply results from the fact that, if $w\in W\smallsetminus K$, i.e. if $\|w\|>2M$, then $\;\|v-w\|>M$.

Indeed, by the second triangle inequality,
$$\|v-w\|\ge\bigl|\|w\|-\|v\|\bigr|=\bigl|\|w\|-M\bigr|>2M-M.$$

Comment: I understand what you use to solve this problem. but one think I want ask is although $\|v-w\| \gt M$, can it be possible to be $\inf\|v-w\|=M$?

Comment: I quess you want to show A contradiction to hypothesis "$\inf\|v-w\| \le M$" so. you show inequality "$\|v-w\| \gt M$". but its infimum may be able to have M.

Comment: No. You proved in your post the $\inf_{\color{red}W}\le M$, and I showed that *outside of* $K$, $\|v-w\|>M$, hence $\inf_{\color{red}{W\smallsetminus K}}\ge M$. Now if the (global) infimum is $<M$, it necessarily is the infimum on $K$.  If the infimum is $M$, it also happens on $K$ since $0\in K$.

Comment: thank you I understand what you said!